# In DC Comics, who is the fastest woman alive?

Tags: dc

In DC Comics, The Flash has the epithet "The fastest man alive." Who is the fastest woman alive?

Answer (score 16):

Since the Flash is the fastest man alive, presumably his female counterparts are the fastest women alive in their universes. There are at least two instances of the Flash being a woman.

From [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/80751/has-there-ever-been-a-female-character-using-the-batman-name/81088#81088) by Thaddeus Howze, the Flash is a woman in Superman #349 from the 1980s.

[image: female Flash in Superman #349]

The [DC Database](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/DC_Comics_Database) also lists a [female Flash](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Flash_(Earth-11)) as a resident of [Earth-11](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Earth-11).

[image: Female Flash in Earth-11]
Picture from the [DC Database](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/File:Flash_Earth-11_001.jpg), which credits *Countdown Presents: The Search for Ray Palmer: Superwoman/Batwoman #1*, February 2008

Comment: Now, if you wanted the fastest woman alive other than the Flash... I don’t know who is next on the list.

Comment: Wasn't there also the Stan Lee female Flash?

Comment: Nice hotpants, Black Condor. You forgot your leggings.

Comment: @Broklynite I remember a series called "Stan Lee Creates..." that had him reimagining character origins for Superman, Batman, et al. Is that the one?

Comment: @Thunderforge Yup, I only ever owned the Flash one, never did get the chance to read the other.

Comment: There also was a female Flash in the Injustice comics, but she appeared only on maybe 4 or 5 panels.

Comment: I suspect that Black Condor is a big fan of musical theater.

Comment: That doesn't follow. The Flash being the fastest man alive means that there aren't any men who are faster than him. It says nothing about there being any women who are faster than him. So if the women Flashes are equally as fast and the man Flash, all we know is that there aren't any men who are faster than them--but there could still be other women who are faster.

Answer (score 11):

I nominate Doralla Kon of Alkomar, introduced in Flash #145, June of 1964.

In her favor: upon arrival, in her perspective, everyone near her was completely and totally frozen, with no effort on her part. Barry Allen had to teach her how to slow down, but when she did, her presence started causing explosive reactions with bodies of water. She only returns one other time hunting a fugitive from her world.

To her detriment - this is not a power. Apparently, folks from Alkomar are just like this. She's not a superheroine, she's an astronaut who just happens to come from a dimension where things move faster.

Out of universe - it is possible this particular dimension is the precursor inspiration for the Speed Force concept introduced in the 90s.

Head Canon - I like to think this chick is the culmination of a family tree of speedsters in the Speed Force who accidentally hung out in Central City in the sixties via space time weirdness.

Comment: Is Doralla Kon faster than the Flash? If so, then she would presumably be faster than the alternate-universe female Flashes. I don't have a problem with it not being a super-power in the same was as Flash. After all, her being fast because she is an alien on a foreign world is like Superman being strong because he's an alien on a foreign world.

Comment: Did you ever get a chance to verify whether Doralla Kon of Alkomar was faster than the Flash? If she is, then I think she's very likely the Fastest Woman alive.

Comment: @thunderforge, sadly, this character arc is pretty old, and the time, money and energy I can afford to spend on research is limited. If I had to guess, nobody can ever be faster than Barry Allen at the top of his game when he was responsible for the creation of the speed force, except by tapping that force directly, which shouldn't canonically be a thing she could do.

Answer (score 5):

**Meena Dhawan is the fastest woman alive.**
[image]

Comment: She certainly has a high opinion of herself. Is this just self-delusion though?

Comment: Is there any other evidence to  support this?

Comment: What comic is that from?

Comment: That page looks like a CW intro @amaranth THE FLASH #5 from 2016